# In cryptocurrency blockchains, how are identical transactions differentiated?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

If there are two different blocks that each give their coinbase to Alice, then their coinbase transactions would theoretically have the exact same data: no tx ins, and one tx out with Alice's address. This would also cause the two transaction hashes to be the same, which shouldn't happen. What is missing in this data structure?

Answer (score 0):

No two block will be identical. Because each block contains previous block information. For example [Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block) block structure shows that there are several elements that prevent from two block being identical like `Transaction counter`, `blockheader` which contains `hashPrevBlock` and `time`.